# Слушатель открытия клавиатуры. Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, клавиатура, listener

Есть `MainActivity` внутри которой располагается `Fragment` с несколькими `EditText`.

Вопрос как перехватить момент когда клавиатура открывается и закрывается? Желательно внутри `MainActivity`, если есть такая возможность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent Решение намного проще используя стороннюю библиотеку

Answer (score 2):

Этот способ будет работать только когда `android:windowSoftInputMode` установлен в `adjustResize` в манифесте. Можно отслеживать изменение размера layout из-за открытия клавиатуры.

Создайте базовый класс для своих активити:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener keyboardLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - rootLayout.getHeight();
            int contentViewTop = getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();

            LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(BaseActivity.this);

            if(heightDiff <= contentViewTop){
                onHideKeyboard();

                Intent intent = new Intent("KeyboardWillHide");
                broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
            } else {
                int keyboardHeight = heightDiff - contentViewTop;
                onShowKeyboard(keyboardHeight);

                Intent intent = new Intent("KeyboardWillShow");
                intent.putExtra("KeyboardHeight", keyboardHeight);
                broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    };

    private boolean keyboardListenersAttached = false;
    private ViewGroup rootLayout;

    protected void onShowKeyboard(int keyboardHeight) {}
    protected void onHideKeyboard() {}

    protected void attachKeyboardListeners() {
        if (keyboardListenersAttached) {
            return;
        }

        rootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener);

        keyboardListenersAttached = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (keyboardListenersAttached) {
            rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener);
        }
    }
}
```

В этом примере одна из View будет скрываться или показываться в зависимости от состояния клавиатуры.

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">              

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <!-- omitted for brevity -->

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <!-- omitted for brevity -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        attachKeyboardListeners();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onShowKeyboard(int keyboardHeight) {
        // do things when keyboard is shown
        bottomContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHideKeyboard() {
        // do things when keyboard is hidden
        bottomContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }        
}
```

Comment: А более лаконичного варианта нету?(